# Formsets are returning as valid=False and not saving

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form that allows teachers to create lessons, which are linked to multiple activities (ManyToMany), which are in turn linked to many Items (ForeignKey). As such, I am using formsets for activities and items. However, activity_formset is coming back as invalid and not saving.

**The View**

```
class N_LessonEditAllView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Lesson
    template_name = 'lessons/edit-lesson.html'
    form_class = LessonForm

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Lesson, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        lesson = self.get_object()
        activity_formset = ActivityFormSet(queryset=lesson.activity.all())
        item_formsets = []

        for activity_form in activity_formset:
            item_formset = ItemFormSet(queryset=Item.objects.filter(activity_id=activity_form.instance.id))
            item_formsets.append(item_formset)

        context['activity_formset'] = activity_formset
        context['item_formsets'] = item_formsets

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        
        context = self.get_context_data()
        activity_formset = context['activity_formset']
        item_formsets = context['item_formsets']

        print('activity_formset is valid:', activity_formset.is_valid())
        print('activity_formset errors:', activity_formset.errors)
        
        for activity_form in activity_formset:
            item_formset = ItemFormSet(queryset=Item.objects.filter(activity_id=activity_form.instance.id))
            item_formsets.append(item_formset)
            print(f'activity_formset for activity {activity_form.instance.id} is valid: {item_formset.is_valid()} --- data {activity_formset.data} --- errors: {activity_formset.errors} --- payload {self.request.POST}')

            
        if activity_formset.is_valid() and all(item_formset.is_valid() for item_formset in item_formsets):
            self.object = form.save()
            activity_formset.instance = self.object
            activity_formset.save()
            print('Form is valid:', form.is_valid())
            print('Activity formset is valid:', activity_formset.is_valid())
            for item_formset in item_formsets:
                print('Item formset is valid:', item_formset.is_valid())
                item_formset.instance = self.object
                item_formset.save()
                
            raise ValueError('Intentional error')
            print(form.cleaned_data)

            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**The Template**

```
<div class="card">
    <form method="post">
    <div class="card-header">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
    </div>
    
    <div class="card-body">
        {% for activity_form in activity_formset %}
        {{ activity_formset.management_form }}
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5>Task {{ forloop.counter }}</h5>
                {{ activity_form|crispy }}
            </div>
            <!--Start of Items_set-->
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ item_formsets.forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}
                {{ item_formsets.0.management_form }}
                {% for item_form in item_formsets.0 %}
                <div class="form-inline">
                {{ item_form|crispy }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            <!--End of Item_set-->
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Returns:**

> activity_formset is valid: False
> activity_formset errors: []
> activity_formset for activity 8 is valid: False --- data {} --- errors: [] --- payload <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['GJ3z6OnViO1GGavFmnzF9ihcT4QdNeznwpZ0qNjbpkwMMk8igWGFHPIQHeFyCktm'], 'title': ['Lesson 12'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['2', '4', '2', '4'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['2', '4', '2', '4'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0', '0', '0', '0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000', '1000', '1000', '1000'], 'form-0-title': ['When was Canada founded?'], 'form-0-answer': ['1867'], 'form-0-level': ['1'], 'form-0-act_type': ['1'], 'form-0-id': ['8', '22', '22'], 'form-0-item_text': ['1562', '1562'], 'form-0-item_type': ['1', '1'], 'form-1-item_text': ['897', '897'], 'form-1-item_type': ['1', '1'], 'form-1-id': ['23', '9', '23'], 'form-2-item_text': ['1912', '1912'], 'form-2-item_type': ['1', '1'], 'form-2-id': ['24', '24'], 'form-3-item_text': ['1812', '1812'], 'form-3-item_type': ['1', '1'], 'form-3-id': ['25', '25'], 'form-1-title': ["What is Canada's Capital?"], 'form-1-answer': ['Ottawa'], 'form-1-level': ['1'], 'form-1-act_type': ['1']}>

**What I've Tried**
I've been hacking at this for the last couple of days, would great appreciate some insight.

I have have tried printing the errors, which come back empty and tried to print them on the page, which also come back empty. I just want it to save.

I also tried reading other solutions, but I'm not sure I am able to relate those situations to this one (maybe I'm not seeing/understanding it).

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the `form_valid` functionality in wrong way. You are calling the `get_context_data` here, which is for sending information from view to template during GET requests. But, the `form_valid` function should get the data from `request.POST` as this method is called after the form is submitted by POST request, hence the data should be coming from a post request. To access the post data, you can try like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    activity_formset = ActivityFormset(self.request.POST)
    item_formset = ItemFormSet(self.request.POST)
    if activity_formset.is_valid() and item_formset.is_valid():
       act_instances = activity_formset.save()
       item_instances = item_formset.save()
       return super().form_valid(form)
    return super().form_invalid(form)
```

But I doubt the `ItemFormSet` will work appropriately. Usually in that case, it is better to define a Nested FormSet beforehand and use it (rather than having two separate FormSets). I would recommend looking into this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/philgyford/django-nested-inline-formsets-example) for example or read this [blog](https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-use-nested-formsets-in-django/) about how to implement nested formsets.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the only approach. Just as a workaround i did.

What I did when I had this issue was, I did not include the Model field in the form but I created a form field in the Model form and handled the value in the Views.

Lets say in your model you have a field named "ModelField" I will ignore that "ModelField" in my forms.py and create a form field called "FormModelField". This way when you validate your form it is still Valid.

Then after validating my form i will save my form then get my "FormModelField" value and then update my "ModelField" with "FormModelField" value.

If i'm wrong then please guide me also with the correct approach. :)